# QPushButton - How to append strings of text in a Line Edit box via PushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I'm starting to learn Qt and coding. I have a basic project in mind, for practice purposes.

Here is a pic of my small UI:

[image: New Screenshot]

Bear with me please because I am just starting in cpp.

I would like the QPushButton to append this string -> "text" inside the text box after I click it.

Clicking twice would result in having "texttext" and so on.

I have seen this question answered:
[QT creating push buttons that add text to a text edit box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199551/qt-creating-push-buttons-that-add-text-to-a-text-edit-box)

The solution mentioned there seems to be what I need, I just don't understand how to integrate it to my project.

Is there anyone that would be able to help out ?

I have these files so far:

test.pro:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h :

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void addTextTolable();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(this-    >addTextToLabel()));
}

void MainWindow::addTextTolable()
{
    ui->textEdit->appendPlainText("test");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

---

This is the last error I have

```
mainwindow.cpp:-1: In member function 'void MainWindow::addTextTolable()':
mainwindow.cpp:14: error: 'class QTextEdit' has no member named   'appendPlainText'
     ui->textEdit->appendPlainText("test");
                   ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to C++ and Qt coding! It's a lot of fun, but there are a lot of things going on. I'll try my best to modify your existing stuff to explain. Classes inherited from QObject send signals to each other through Qt's signal/slot architecture. So, this is what you'll do.

1.) Declare a slot function in the mainwindow header file. This is just a normal function declaration, except placed under a slots: tab.

2.) Connect the signal from the QPushButton's "clicked(bool)" to the mainwindow slot, usually in the MainWindow constructor

So here's the modified code.

mainwindow.h :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    /*IMPORTANT NOTE: Q_OBJECT must appear in the beginning of the header of any object you want to use signals/slots for*/
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

/*Declare the function to be called when the QPushButton is clicked*/
private slots:
    void addTextToLabel();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /*It's very important to note that doing anything with the ui object must be done AFTER ui->setupUi(this) is called. The program will segfault otherwise*/
     /*General connect syntax:
       connect(object that will emit signal, SIGNAL(signal emitted), object that will receive the signal, SLOT(slot function));
     /*the pushButton is owned by the ui object*/
     connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel());
}

/*Now define the slot function*/
void MainWindow::addTextToLabel()
{
    /*I actually can't tell from the UI whether the text box is a plainTextEdit or textEdit, so substitute the name of the text box (found in the QDesigner window)*/
    ui->textEdit->appendText("test");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Give that a shot and let me know if anything goes awry or you have any more questions.

Comment: I figured out all the some errors, just a last one I cannot seem get rid of. I updated my post accordingly. If you have time to help would be great :)

Comment: Ah, yes. The QTextEdit does not contain that method, only the QPlainTextEdit. Instead of the "ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("test")" line, use "ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + "test");"

Comment: Your correction or "append" instead of "appendPlainText" both get rid of the error. Yay! but I have a new one now: "QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::this->addTextToLabel() in ..\test\mainwindow.cpp:10" --- "QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')" -- "QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')" The application runs now, but the button does not add the text in the box

Comment: Sorry about that, I believe the problem to be that the SLOT() call cann't include the "this" pointer. So instead of "SLOT(this->addTextToLabel())", it should be "SLOT(addTextToLabel())". This is because both the SIGNAL and SLOT calls are already prefaced with the object directly before them.

Comment: Oh I see, that's why. It works now. This is great! Thank you very much